# Is it possible to avoid rewriting code when using both Flask-SQLAlchemy & pydantic?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I'm writing a flask application with Flask-SQLAlchemy for the ORM. I also want to use Pydantic for validation. But this means I have to write a separate schema for Pydantic with the same fields as my SQLAlchemy model. Is this achievable without duplicating code?